# I'm having trouble getting random elements from ArrayList<Coord>

Tags: java, arraylist, random

First, I have Arraylist "listVertex" storing "coordinates" of DTNHost. Second, I created a method to get random elements for the selected index from listVertex ArrayList. However, the following methods generate new coordinate points and the values x and y change from the initial value I have specified.
Please guys, help me to get random elements from theVertex list without having to generate new coordinate points and the value x, y does not change. Thanks for the attention.

```
//retrieve node coordinates from DTNHost.
public void getVertex() {

        List<DTNHost> allNode = SimScenario.getInstance().getHosts();

        for (DTNHost host : allNode) {
            if (host.toString().startsWith("kota")) {
                listVertex.add(host.getLocation());
            }
        }
    }

    //get for random elements from the listVertex ArrayList
    public ArrayList<Coord> randomVeretx(int max) {
        Random r = new Random();
        ArrayList<Coord> result = new ArrayList<Coord>();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            result.add(new Coord(r.nextDouble() * max, r.nextDouble() * max));
        }
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Or the fields in `Coord` are static

Comment: Your title does not coincide with your description. What are you trying to achieve? You have the following comment ` //search for random elements from the listVertex ArrayList ` in a method that does not seems to be called somewhere

Comment: @ThomasKläger More likely than my suggestion.

Comment: @Melron I'm sorry that my English writing confused you. First of all, I still have trouble speaking English. Second, I've edited the "comment code" question above. so, I want to say that I want to get help with how to get random elements from theVertex ArrayList list.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Filed in Coord is not static. So do I have to turn the field in Coord static?

Comment: @ThomasKläger You can get a random element from a list by using the Random class.
 theVertex.get(new Random().nextInt(theVertex.size()));

Comment: @Melron Okay. I'm trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method to get `max` random elements from the `listVertex` (which should be defined as an instance field) may be as follows:

```java
public List<Coord> randomVertex(int max) {
    Random r = new Random();
    List<Coord> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        result.add(vertexList.get(r.nextInt(vertexList.size())));
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, this implementation may contain duplicated coordinates from `vertexList`.

But as long as `max` can be greater than `vertexList.size()` this may be fine.

---

Another approach to get a random list is to use shuffling of the `vertexList`:

```java
public List<Coord> randomVertex(int max) {
    List<Coord> result = new ArrayList<>(vertexList); // copy of vertexList

    Collections.shuffle(result);

    Random r = new Random(); // or use ThreadLocalRandom.current()

    if (max < result.size()) {
        // result is shuffled and therefore randomized
        // no duplicate vertex appear in the result here
        result = result.subList(0, max); 
    } else { // add randomly more elements
        while (result.size() < max) {
            result.add(result.get(r.nextInt(result.size())));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```